# Hibernate qbe don't take sub objects into account

Tags: java, hibernate

I use qbe (query by example) to find some objects in my database. How can i make my query to take into account the child objets too.

For example, I have this object :

```
public class Derogation 
{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "derogation_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "derogation_seq_gen", sequenceName = "calamar.derogation_id_seq",initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Application application;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="derogation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<DerogationAutre> listDerogationAutre;

    [...]
}
```

And i would like to be able to do that :

```
Derogation derogation = new Derogation();
derogation.setApplication(new Application());
derogation.getApplication().setNom("applicationName");

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Derogation.class);
criteria.add(Example.create(derogation));

ArrayList<Derogation> listDerogation = (ArrayList<Derogation>) criteria.list();
```

And to have to get a list that would take in account the applicationName and not only the parameter of my object Derogation.

And to be able to do the same for my list, is it possible ?

### EDIT 1

I was thinking about merging two criteria queries, one about the Derogation and one about the Application but it don't seems to be possible ..

Comment: Waoh man ! I was writing another thing before and i forget to change the title haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found a correct way to do it !

Here is the code :

```
Derogation derogation = new Derogation();
derogation.setApplication(new Application());
derogation.getApplication().setNom("applicationName");

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Derogation.class);
criteria.add(Example.create(derogation));

//For the ManyToOne child
criteria.createCriteria("application").add(Example.create(derogation.getApplication()));

//For the OneToMany child
for(DerogationLinux derogationLinux : derogation.getListDerogationLinux())
    criteria.createCriteria("listDerogationLinux").add(Example.create(derogationLinux));
```

Hope it will help someone one day ;)